# How to change the properties of login control individually

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In asp.net 3.5, I am using a login control which has an id. When i set the id's font to bold, it sets all the fields to bold. for eg., the login control has "Username", "Password" & "Remember Me" and i want to set only the username & password fields bold and leave the remember field to normal.

My code is here -

```
    <asp:Login runat="server"  
        id="BlogLogin"  UserNameLabelText="Username" TitleText="" 
        MembershipProvider="EktronMembershipProvider" LoginButtonText="Login" RememberMeText="Remember Me"
        DisplayRememeberMe="False">   
        </asp:Login>
```

How do i set this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LoginControl,s smart tag click "Conver to Template" now all the controls become seperate.So you change the styles as you want.

Comment: i am using the logincontrol inside a content block(ektron control) and i dont see the smart tag for this logincontrol.

Answer (score 0):

View the source created by the login control. There should be a label or span or something in the HTML that you can access to set the styling. Set a CSS class for the two labels to bold that you want to be bold.  HTH

CSS

```
label.boldClass 
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<label class="boldClass">Username</label>
<label class="boldClass">Password</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion webtrifusion